# custom Html helper issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to convert some user control build for webform to html helpers.

So for example I need to convert the custom controls below to html helper :

```
public class DisGrid : Panel
    {
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("<div class=\"disgrid\"><div>");
            base.Render(writer);
            writer.WriteLine("</div></div>");
        }
    }
```

How Can I do this?

I did it this way but I got an error saying that DisclaimerWidget does not implement inherited abstract member 'project1.Helpers.HtmlWidget.BeginWidget()'

```
 public class DisGridWidget : HtmlWidget
    {

        public DisGridWidget(ViewContext viewContext) : base(viewContext)
        {
            this.BeginWidget();
        }

        protected void BeginWidget()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("<div class='disgrid'><div>");


            this._textWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

           protected override void EndWidget()
        {
            this._textWriter.WriteLine("</div></div>");
        }
    }
```

or there s another way to do it ?

and how to use it in a view?

Comment: Try changing protected void BeginWidget() to protected override void BeginWidget().

Comment: @Middas it fixed the error. thank you.and how can I use the helper in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, change `protected void BeginWidget()` to `protected override void BeginWidget()`

As for your second question, I'm unfamiliar with the `HtmlWidget` base class.  The way I've seen widgets done in the past is by calling `@Html.Partial()` or using `Html.Action()`.  I believe there are some open source projects out there that add an `HtmlHelper` extension for widgets as well.

http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html is a great resource to introduce `Html.Partial()`

http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2011/11/htmlpartial-vs-htmlaction-mvc-razor.html is a great resource that explains `Html.Action()` and how it differs from `Html.Partial()`